# Where can I download driver for my LAN card on board

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Belarc advisor says that my board is

Board: nVIDIA NF-MCP61 
BIOS: Phoenix Technologies, LTD 6.00 PG 09/18/2009

http://www.nvidia.com/object/nforce_nf4_winxp32_8.26_11.09.html

If I search on the net I saw a link to xp driver.

I want windows 7 64 driver.

If I go to nvidia and select my product I am given an option

nforce 9 series
nforce 8 series

How the hell I know the series? Belarc advisor said that my board is  nVIDIA NF-MCP61

The problem is the lan card won't work until I connect to internet. So I can't use microsoft driver till the lan card work. But I can't get the lan card work till I got a driver. And I can't get a driver till the internet works.

Comment: You want a password for Win7 x64? What password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No win7 64 driver for your board.Last driver was for VISTA. 
No support for Nforce as it was discontinued. 
Chance are trying to use the updated driver from Microsoft by device manager's update drivers.

This is MCP61 Drivers
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Product Type: Legacy
Product Series: nForce 4 series
Product: nForce 430/Geforce 6150SE

Comment: The problem is the lan card won't work until I connect to internet. So I can't use microsoft driver till the lan card work. But I can't get the lan card work till I got a driver. And I can't get a driver till the internet works.

Comment: By the way it does work. Thanks a lot. I'll use vista driver and see how it goes.